# Uncaught ReferenceError: functionName is not defined from import

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have separated JS functions from different web pages (index, login, register and others) into their own JS files which are then imported to the main JS file, that includes functions that are shared across more than one page. I have done this for the purpose of maintenance and readability of code (I hope), otherwise I would have hundreds of lines of code in one file.

**login.js**

```
export function loginSubmit() {
  $("#login-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    let formValid;

    $("#login-form input").each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        fieldInputInvalid($(this));
        formValid = false;
      }
    });

    if (formValid !== false) {
      // submit the form for authentication
    }
  });
}
```

**register.js**

```
export function loginSubmit() {
  $("#register-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    let formValid;

    // other form validation functions (not shown as not necessary to post)  

    $("#register-form input").each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        fieldInputInvalid($(this));
        formValid = false;
      }
    });

    if (formValid !== false) {
      // submit the form for user registration
    }
  });
}
```

**main.js**

```
// import all functions from these js files
import * as login from "../scripts/login.js";
import * as register from "../scripts/register.js";

// general functions used on more than one page
function fieldInputInvalid(inputField) {
  // Changes styling of inputField to display to user that it is invalid.
}

function fieldInputValid(inputField) {
  // Changes styling of inputField to display to user that it is valid.
}

function createElement(elemName, elemAttributes) {
  // Create document element
  var elem = document.createElement(elemName);
  // Check if element attirbutes were passed
  if (elemAttributes !== "undefined") {
    // Loop through each argument
    $.each(elemAttributes, function (key, value) {
      // and assign it to the document element
      elem.setAttribute(key, value);
    });
  }
  // Return document element
  return elem;
}
```

As you can see from my code samples, both the login.js and register.js functions call the function fieldInputInvalid() from main.js, however, I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: fieldInputInvalid is not defined` error when either forms are submitted. I know that I can get around this by putting the fieldInputInvalid function into both login.js and register.js, but I thought this would break the do not duplicate code rule. Is there a way to get this to work with my current structure or a better way to achieve the result I desire?

(NOTE: I have many other general functions that are not included in this post that would be used across my website. I am aware that I could put the code from login.js and register.js together into one file named identity.js with the fieldInputInvalid and fieldInputValid functions and then export, but this would not solve any of the other general functions that are included in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `fieldInputInvalid` in its own file, and then have `login` and `register` import it:

```
// fieldInputInvalid.js
export const fieldInputInvalid = () => {
  // ...
}
```

```
// login.js
import { fieldInputInvalid } from './fieldInputInvalid';
// ...
```

Another option would be, whenever `loginSubmit` is called, pass it the `fieldInputInvalid` function, if you can, eg:

```
loginSubmit(fieldInputInvalid);
```

```
// login.js (and register.js):
export function loginSubmit(fieldInputInvalid) {
  // ...
```

Then you'll be able to call `fieldInputInvalid` inside `loginSubmit`.

If you have multiple shared functions and you don't want to pass each one individually, you could also pass an *object* of functions to all `loginSubmit`s, like:

```
loginSubmit({ fieldInputInvalid, someOtherHelper });
```

```
// login.js (and register.js):
export function loginSubmit({ fieldInputInvalid, someOtherHelper }) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I will give it a try but I notice that by doing it this way, would mean that all of my general functions would need to be put into a seperate js file and my main.js file would just be a file of imported js functions. Is this okay or valid from a professional standpoint?

Comment: Yeah, I'd want to put all the general functions (which are used many places) into their own files. It depends how long the functions are - if they're short, you could put them all into a single file. If they're long, it'd probably be more maintainable to have separate files for each function (which is what I do). After that point, you still have the choice to either have each `loginSubmit` import those files, or import them where `loginSubmit` is called and pass an object of functions down instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing that up. You have been of great help!